# select query in selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't find a correct query for this next problem. (see image)

[image]

Hereby this table Schedule where day 1 is Monday, day 2 is Tuesday, .. 
I have to find out which teacher is free on Monday during the first hour but is present at school because he/she has to teach later on that day. So the result may only give John and Suzan, but not Mark and Tom because they don't have to teach that day.

I tried simple query and nested queries but none give the correct result.

```
select distinct Teacher from Schedule where Day = 1 and Hour <> 1 order by Teacher  ASC  

select distinct Teacher from Schedule where Day = 1 and NOT Hour = 1 order by Teacher  ASC
```

More complex queries don't make any difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post text not images

Answer (score 3):

In that special case it might be possible to use aggregation. Check if the minimum hour of the day of the teacher is greater than 1.

```
SELECT teacher
       FROM schedule
       WHERE day = 1
       GROUP BY teacher
       HAVING min(hour) > 1;
```

A more general approach for any day and any hour might use conditional aggregation. Only count, if the teacher teaches a specific hour at the day. So, when the count is 0, we know they don't teach at the hour given.

```
SELECT teacher
       FROM schedule
       WHERE day = ?
       GROUP BY teacher
       HAVING count(CASE
                      WHEN hour = ? THEN
                        1
                    END) = 0;
```

(Replace the `?` with the values for the day or the hour, respectively.)

Yet another approach is to use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.teacher
       FROM schedule s1
       WHERE s1.day = ?
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM schedule s2
                                    WHERE s2.day = s1.day
                                          AND s2.teacher = s1.teacher
                                          AND s2.hour = ?);
```

If you have a table with all teachers, you could also use that as a source and filter by `EXISTS` (for the day) and `NOT EXISTS` (for the day and hour) targeting `schedule`.